# Use to socket.io all the project page

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, serversocket

Hello I want to use socket.io in all my page so I want to use socket in my Header.php for notifications. But i dont know how can i do this.

ForExample i want to use socket in my page of  xxxx.com/chat.php , xxxx.com/Messages.php and xxxx.com/MainPage.php.  I write on npm "node server.js" i can use it just localhost:(Port number) i use it just here. i want to use it in my all page.... how can i do this ?

This is my server code.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);

var io=require('socket.io')(http);


app.get("/",function(req,res){

    res.sendfile(__dirname+"/index.html");


});


io.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log("User Connected");
});


var port=80;
http.listen(port,function(){
    console.log(port+". port Listening..");
});
```

I want to use it in my XAMPP port i want to listen 80 port. But i cant do this. User isnt connected. I can use it just index.html on diffrent to 80 port.

Comment: I am slightly lost with what you actually want to achieve

Comment: how can we do it ?